# I need to set a webview and add some other elements after it in WP8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I am making an application for WP 8.1 and I receive, from an API a string I have to show, with some html elements, so, to show it, I have to put a webview in xaml.

Prior to it, I have a few textblocks and an image and after the textview I will have some other textblocks and may have another image as well; and everything needs to be wraped into a scrolviewer.

My problem is that: - If I set the webview directly, everything after it won´t be seen. - If I put a grid over it I solve that problem, but I am not able to determine the height of the grid to cover everything (like: which formula can I use to see how much is the height of the webview?)

How can I properly set this?

```
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="descriptionNoChildOnly" Margin="0,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Grid Background="White">
            <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="titleNoChild" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,20,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="open sans" FontSize="28" Width="360" Height="Auto" Foreground="Black"/>
            <Image Height="Auto" x:Name="imageNoChild" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <WebView x:Name="descNoChild" Width="380" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,100,10,0" DefaultBackgroundColor="#FFF3F3F3"/>
            <Grid Background="Transparent" Width="400" Height="10.25" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

> which formula can I use to see how much is the height of the webview?

You can use the `ElementName` binding to bind to the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`of another element (tested this code on a Windows Store App). This gives you a `Grid` whose dimensions will be same as that of the `WebView`.

```
<WebView Source="http://www.google.com" Width="300" Height="300" Name="descNoChild"/>
<Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=descNoChild,Path=ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=descNoChild,Path=ActualHeight}"/>

// Grid Width and Height will be 300
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution which i think can work for you, if you want to arrange all your elements top-down and wrap them inside a scrollviewer so that you may have the liberty of scrolling the items.

Then your answer is using a StackPanel inside the scrollviewer that will house all the other element.

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <StackPanel>
      ...Other elements go in here
   </StackPanel>
</ScollViewer>
```

With this, you dont have to worry about other elements over-lapping on top of each other.

Hope thats what you are asking.